# C# Threading: Pause Main Thread until Sub Thread is closed.

Tags: c#, multithreading

My problem is simple. I have an application, in which I create and call a sub thread. My sub thread launches a notepad, where a user inputs some values and then closes it. My application then takes the information from the notepad for additional processing. 
The problem is that my main thread doesn't wait for the sub thread to end 
(notepad to be closed), to perform the additional processing.

I could have used a form to gather these inputs, but I wish to have a program that is minimalistic. Today, the inputs are from a notepad. Tommorow, it may be from MS Office or OpenOffice.
Can someone please provide some guidance?
Regards.

Comment: Well, to me providing a form with a simple edit control for text input, sounds much more "minimalistic" than launching notepad. Then properly waiting for it to finish, grabbing it's content (do you use a temporary file or force the user to copy to clipboard?), and also handle all sorts of failure conditions. YMMV of course.

Comment: How are you launching notepad? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a simpler approach here. The Process class has an Exited event that you can sign up for:

```
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += (o, e) =>
                              {
                                  Console.WriteLine("Closed");
                              };
        process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you need is `Thread.Join`

Comment: What exactly was the point of kalyan's edit? Low hanging fruit to gain a bit of rep...

Comment: @alex - I'm confused - you don't get rep by editing other people's questions do you?

Comment: you do if you're under 2k. You get 2 points for each edit that's approved by users with over 2k. Once you reach 2000 points, you no longer get any points. The downside of this new rule is that a lot of lower rep users change a trivial thing and (slowly) accumulate points.

Comment: @alex, Please dont under estimate users here. The "Thread.Join" seems to me belongs to a code part, so I changed it.

Comment: BFree - Thank you. I've integrated your code to my work. And by the looks of thing, it's solves my problem. I will just need to declare some boolean variable, and set it to true when the "Exit" is fired.
Tried the "Thread.join" code but i was getting nowhere with it.
Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In the code for the helper thread:

```
using ( Process p = Process.Start(...your parameters here...) ) {
    // waits for the user to close the document
    p.WaitForExit();
    // TODO: postprocessing of the edited document
}
```

In your Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    ...
    Thread helperThread = // TODO: create thread
    helperThread.Start();
    // TODO: do other things
    ...
    // Wait for the helper thread to exit
    helperThread.Join();
}
```

You have to wait for the started process to exit (`Process.WaitForExit`) *and* wait for the thread to exit as well (`Thread.Join`).

That said, you don't have to use a separate thread, you can start the process in the main thread. Editing of the document runs in parallel anyway. Just use `WaitForExit` when you need the output.